# How to check if file can be deleted by an android application?

Tags: android

How do I know if a file can be deleted by my android application?

I am writing an android application and a web application that will allow my clients to view and delete their files.
But I will not let the client to view the files that are undeletable.

Like

```
if(isFileCanBeDeleted("filename.ext"))
{
  //save the filename and path to server
}
else
{
   //the file is cannot be deleted, this filename will not be saved online
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try by executing shell command,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test -e " + "/path/to/file.txt");
```

However, you need to check API references whether shell runtime is available or not, depending on API Level, or root/non-rooted phone.